# Is Bootstrap 2.1 compatible with jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

It's a known problem that the older Bootstrap didn't work out of the box with jQuery UI, as you can see from [this github discussion](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/156).

There are a few mashups of the two, including [jQuery Bootstrap](http://jslegers.github.com/jquery-bootstrap/) by John Seigers and [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/) by Addy Osmani.

Are those mashups still necessary with the new version of Bootstrap, or can you now just use Bootstrap and jQuery UI out of the box (as is alluded to vaguely in the github discussion)?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the github discussion. I am not aware that it would be compatible, but if so, I would highly appreciate :-)

Comment: @schacki -- link is indeed there, on the words "this github discussion" in the first sentence :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am implementing a solution which is using Twitter Bootstrap 2.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.23 and I haven't experience any trouble so far.
Apparently Twitter Bootstrap v2 no longer conflicts with jquery ui.
You can find some more infos [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/171).

Mark Otto [states](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4566)

> We cannot guarantee compatibility with other frameworks like jQuery UI
>   ...

so I guess you might have problems with some jQuery UI components and ask them to help you and find a solution.

At the moment I have a few problems with jqGrid.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Besides these vague forum comments from Twitter, are you aware of any more official statement about this conflict? I'm hoping to a more definitive answer before diving in without the use of the mashups.

Comment: @Ghopper21: as they say they can't guarantee compatibility but they seem to be happy to help if someone has troubles (updated my answer).

Comment: Out of context comment changes the meaning. This is the full comment. `We cannot guarantee compatibility with other frameworks like jQuery UI, especially when you do not include a jsfiddle or any demo`